# How to allow downloading any file type with auto open

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mime-types

ASP.NET MVC 4 applications stores files in a database and allows downloading them.

Postgres table dokumarh has two columns

- filename text  Name of file which was posted using
- content  bytea  file content as binary data.

Application allows downloading files from browser. Downloaded files should open the default OS application for that extension. Example, doc for word, xls for excel, txt for notepad etc.

This feature is implemented using controller

```
        public FileStreamResult ShowDocument(string filename)
        {
           var manus = Db.QuerySingle(@"
select filename, content
from dokumarh 
where filename=@0
", filename);
            return new FileStreamResult(new  MemoryStream(manus.content), "???")
            {
                FileDownloadName = manus.filename
            };
        }
```

MVC filestreamresult requires sent parameter and content type marked with "???"

During upload, only the filename is available; there is no content type.

How can I specify proper content type? Or is it possible to return just the filename without specifying content type? Or is there a MVC method, database or library which can find the content type from the file extension?

Comment: You can use the [MimeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.aspx) class

Comment: Ah ! I never knew about it. Thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke This solves the issue. You can wrote it as answer so I can mark and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static `GetMimeMapping()` method of [System.Web.MimeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.aspx) to return the MIME mapping for a file name. The class contains a private dictionary containing all known extensions and their associated MIME types

For example

```
string fileName = "myfile.pdf";
string MineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName); // returns "application/pdf"
```